# Mapping section into own address space

Tags: windows, memory, mapping, internals

So i got a little bit lost looking at memory mapping.
There is shared memory which requires implementation on both processes.
Then there is the possibility to inject a file using MapViewOfSection.

I've implemented these two things and didn't have many problems with them.
However to finish my journey I want to map a part of another process into mine (so I can access the same physical address from within my process).

Is this possible within usermode (I think I'm not ready for driver development yet)?
I'm not sure about the steps I have to take.
Logically I would need to know which section I want to map. Open a handle to it and then use NTMapViewOfSection to map it but how would that look in detail?

Comment: You can read and modify the memory another process using ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory.  If you want to share memory between two processes they need to cooperate.  NtMapViewOfSection isn't supported for user-mode processes (you should be using CreateFileMapping) and AFAIK most of the interesting parts of a process's address space aren't in sections anyway.